# How to use Dockerfile RUN or CMD command to execute the next silent installation

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to emulate the next Unix command in a Dockerfile:

```
./DAEJA_VIEWONE_5.0.x_UNIX_ML.bin -i silent -f DAEJA_VIEWONE_silent_install.txt
```

As you can see is a silent installation for the viewer of Daeja.I think the Dockerfile commands for realize this are RUN or CMD but I can not find an example of how i can achieve this.

I tried to add the next Dockerfile command but it fail:

```
RUN ./DAEJA_VIEWONE_5.0.x_UNIX_ML.bin -i silent -f DAEJA VIEWONE silent_install.txt
```

just as @Paolo suggested

I add the Dockerfile and the console error for ilustrative purposes.

[image]

The Dockerfile as a text:

```
FROM alpine:3.14

RUN mkdir /project

COPY DAEJA_VIEWONE_5.0.13_UNIX_ML.bin /project

COPY DAEJA_VIEWONE_silent_install.txt /project

WORKDIR /project

RUN chmod a+x DAEJA_VIEWONE_5.0.13_UNIX_ML.bin

RUN chmod a+x DAEJA_VIEWONE_silent_install.txt

RUN ./DAEJA_VIEWONE_5.0.x_UNIX_ML.bin -i silent -f DAEJA_VIEWONE_silent_install.txt
```

There is an error in this line, the version number is missing. When that is fixed it starts to work. The version number is 5.0.13 as shown above (copy paste error)
**RUN ./DAEJA_VIEWONE_5.0.x_UNIX_ML.bin -i silent -f DAEJA_VIEWONE_silent_install.txt**

Thanks!

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: I assume you're thalking about a category or tag, where I can find that ?

Comment: Anyway the error is clear. You need to either use `ADD` or `COPY` to get the .bin file into the image

Comment: I guess you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. But there are other SE sites for. your question

Comment: @Paolo How can I check the content of /project to kwown that the files is in it ?

Comment: You should remove `RUN mkdir /project` and in its place use `WORKDIR /project`

Comment: @Paolo your answer was correct, now is working. In this moment I an accepting your original reply. There was a sintax problem in the last line lack the number versión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the right Dockerfile instruction to run something at build time is `RUN`:

```
RUN ./DAEJA_VIEWONE_5.0.x_UNIX_ML.bin -i silent -f DAEJA_VIEWONE_silent_install.txt
```

obviously assuming that `DAEJA_VIEWONE_5.0.x_UNIX_ML.bin` is present in the working directory.

I suggest you review the Dockerfile documentation to understand what each instruction does:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

to sum up, `RUN` is used at build time to run a command, whereas `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` define what the container should do when started.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response:
I tried what you suggested, and this was the result: **ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh** Right on the same line where I executed the RUN command. I'm going to edit the question and add some more usefull info.

Comment: @nicolastpi01 show us your entire Dockerfile